# C# Web Forms navigation through pages error

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

Hello i have tried almost everything  i found on the internet about "Cross Page Postback".i succesfully transfer to WebForm2  but the previous page is always null so i can not receive any data from the WebForm1.
Here is what i added to my WebForm1.aspx:

```
           <div>
           <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txttransferid" Visible="false"></asp:TextBox>
            <asp:Button ID="btntransfer" runat="server" PostBackUrl="~/WebForm2.aspx"/>
          </div>
```

Here is what i added to my WebForm2.aspx:

```
         <%@ PreviousPageType VirtualPath="~/WebForm1.aspx" %>
```

Here is what i added to my WebForm2.cs:

```
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (PreviousPage != null)
            {
               var id= ((TextBox)PreviousPage.FindControl("txttransferid")).Text;
            }
        }
```

I also tried  Server.Transfer with async PageLoad this time.

Code on WebForm1.cs

```
            protected void btntransfer_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
              Server.Transfer("~/WebForm2.aspx");
            }
```

With this WebForm2.cs code:

```
          protected async void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
          {
              if (!Page.IsPostBack)
              {
                if (PreviousPage != null)
                {
                var id=((TextBox)PreviousPage.FindControl("txttransferid")).Text;
                }
                var response = await APIGetOrderDetails(Convert.ToInt32(id),1);
                DataSet ds = (DataSet)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(response, 
                (typeof(DataSet)));
                OrderDetailGrid.DataSource = ds;
                OrderDetailGrid.DataBind();
              }
           }
```

With Server.Transfer i succesfully transfer to WebForm2  and the previous page is not null so i can receive any data from the WebForm1 but i always get immediately this error "System.Web.HttpException: 'Error executing child request for /WebForm1.aspx

InnerException "InvalidOperationException: HttpServerUtility.Execute blocked while waiting for an asynchronous operation to complete."

At the end i tried to do this at WebForm1 :

```
         protected async void btntransfer_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
         {
            await Task.Run(() => Server.Transfer("~/WebForm2.aspx"));
         }
```

The error went away but the grid i wanted to load was never loaded.

Any ideas please?thanks!

Comment: Did you try server.transfer with normal page_load?

Comment: Hello yes and it works fine but i need that async tag

Comment: Did you debug and check what's wrong with the code?

Comment: of course i did

Comment: And what's wrong with the code?

Comment: as i said in the description in "Cross Page Postback" i succesfully transfer to WebForm2 but the previous page is always null so i can not receive any data from the WebForm1 and with server transfer i cant use the async tag

Comment: why are you not using `Sessions` ?